# How do I call a controller action on the user exiting the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I add a bunch of records to my table during a user`s session. Once the user exits the session (closes the window, goes to a different website etc.) I want to be able to call a function like so:

```
def clear_list
    Shoe.where(user_id: @user_id).destroy_all
end
```

I know that `before_filter` enables you to call a controller action as the page loads. What can I use to call an action on page close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Destroying a session" and "closing a page" don't mean the same thing.

I guess you're looking for a `before_destroy` callback for your `Session` model.

See [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something with jquery here is another question about it: [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser), but im not sure you would be able to run code before the page gets closed, you are better off handling sessions and background process.